# opencv - unable to capture frame from camera on raspberry pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

My pi camera is connected and enabled, raspistill takes photos successfully. In python, cv2.VideoCapture(-1).read() always returns (False, None). I'm stumped.

Comment: That's done the trick, thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OpenCV** relies on the V4L2 (Video for Linux) module, so try adding the following line at the bottom of the file `/etc/modules` and rebooting your Raspberry Pi.

```
bcm2835-v4l2
```

Mine now looks like this *in toto*:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

bcm2835-v4l2
```

This ensures that the **Broadcom Video For Linux 2** (v4l2) driver is loaded at all subsequent reboots.

Comment: and in some cases also change the picamera ( camera hardware issue)