# My raspberry pi camera does not return frames to opencv

Tags: python, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, camera

I have a raspberry pi camera module 3 connected to raspberry pi. It is connected properly, since `libcamera-still -o test.jpg` works as intended.
But when I try to capture a stream of frames, I get this error message `error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'`.

My code looks like this:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCpture(0)

while True:
   _, image = cap.read()
   cv2,imshow("video stream", image)
   if(cv2.waitkey(1) == ord("q")):
      break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried what this post says: [opencv - unable to capture frame from camera on raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288141/opencv-unable-to-capture-frame-from-camera-on-raspberry-pi) but it did not help.

Comment: your code lacks error checking. `isOpened()` missing and `cap.read()` returns a tuple, the first element of which you should never discard and always check. and you need to check with guvcview or vlc whether this camera is a regular V4L camera. this `libcamera-still` stuff is probably not using standard V4L APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution that worked for me looks kinda like this(I am using picamera2 to capture the camera frames and cv2 to show those frames in a window):

```
picam2 = Picamera2()
picam2.start()
while True:
   image = picam2.capture_array()
   cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
   if(cv2.waitkey(1) == ord("q")):
      cv2.imwrite("test_frame.png", image)
      break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `cv2.VideoCpture(0)` you can try install on your Pi -  Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy, 64-bit) Bullseye.
This problem you encountered is most probably caused by a lack of some drivers on newer versions of Raspberry PI OS. Any advices from forums didn't help me to fix this problem on the latest OS version.

So, only this solution works for me:

1. Install Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy, 64-bit) Bullseye. Exact version I use is "11 (bullseye)"
2. sudo raspi-config  -> Interface Options -> Legacy Camera Enable
3. sudo apt update
4. sudo apt install python3-opencv -y

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it's a typo: `cv2,imshow` -> `cv2.imshow`

Comment: if you see a typo and you believe that's the actual issue, then you should flag/vote to close the question as due to a typo.